# Use Java concurrency to run a multi-threaded task until there is enough output

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, threadpool, executor

I have a task in Java that is currently single threaded and may or may not produce output.   I need to run this task until I have 100 pieces of output from it.  Here is the single threaded (greatly simplified) example version of this:

```
import java.security.SecureRandom;

public class Test {

    private static SecureRandom rand = new SecureRandom();

    public static String task() {
        return rand.nextDouble() > 0.5 ? "output" : null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int outputCount = 0;
        while (outputCount < 100) {
            String output = task();
            if (output != null) {
                outputCount++;
                System.out.println(output);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to run this task multi-threaded in four (4) threads.  How do I implement it?

I've looked into using the [Executor interfaces](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/exinter.html) but they appear to be geared at running a task exactly n times, not until needed.

Some additional notes:

- I don't care if I get 103 pieces of output and have to discard 3 of them
- One object that the task uses is expensive to construct, is not thread safe, but could be used again by a task that runs later.  (This is represented by the SecureRandom in the above example.)   Ideally, I'd like a thread pool that lets me instantiate exactly four of these objects.

Comment: You need some kind queue or manager which the other threads can communicate with. Each thread would then append/add there results to this manager (the manager will need to ensure that access is synchronised properly). Each thread would loop until the queue stopped accepting new input. You can use Executors to do this, you just need to keep each callable looping internally until the need to stop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest approach:

- Use [AtomicInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) to make the count thread safe (as suggested by [Alexander Pogrebnyak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/185722/alexander-pogrebnyak)'s answer)
- Use an [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) which can `invokeAll` a list of [Callable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) and wait until they all finish.
- Put `SecureRand rand` and `String task()` as member elements of the Callable
- Move the loop inside the Callable's `call()` method, have each thread complete tasks until there are no more tasks to complete.

Here is the implementation:

```
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
public class Test {
    private static final int TASKS = 100;
    private static final int THREADS = 4;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {        
        final AtomicInteger outputCount = new AtomicInteger(0);
        ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(THREADS);
        Collection<Callable<Object>> tasks = new ArrayList<>(THREADS);
        for (int i = 0; i < THREADS; i++) {
            tasks.add(new Callable<Object>() {
                private SecureRandom rand = new SecureRandom();
                private String task() {
                    return rand.nextDouble() > 0.5 ? Thread.currentThread().getName() : null;
                }
                @Override public Object call() {
                    for (int i; (i = outputCount.get()) < TASKS;) {
                        String output = task();
                        if (output != null) {
                            if ((i = outputCount.incrementAndGet()) < TASKS) {
                                System.out.println(output + ": " + i);
                            }
                        }
                    } return null;
                }
            });
        }
        threadPool.invokeAll(tasks);
        threadPool.shutdownNow();
        System.out.println("done");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think in your case you can use just an [AtomicInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) that is shared between your tasks.

```
public class MyTask
  implements Runnable
{
  private AtomicInteger counter;

  public MyTask ( AtomicInteger counter )
  {
    this.counter = counter;
  }

  public void run ()
  {
    while ( true )
    {
      String output = task();
      if ( output != null )
      {
        int count = counter.getAndIncrement( );

        System.out.println(output);
        if ( count >= 100 )
        {
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  public static String task() {
    return rand.nextDouble() > 0.5 ? "output" : null;
  }

  public static void main (
      String[] args
    ) throws InterruptedException
  {
    AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger( );

    ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        pool.execute( new MyTask( counter ) );
    }

    // Simplified shutdown, do not use this in production
    pool.shutdown( );
    pool.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.HOURS);
  }
}
```

Comment: `while ( true )` could be `while (counter.get() < 100)` to prevent some needless work when it is already known there is enough output.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller. No, because then you lose atomicity.  You should do 'getAndIncrement' only when you've met your condition (that the output is availabe).  It only works here because you specified that you do not care about 'exact' number of times you execute `task` method.  For `exact` number of executions you need a more elaborate setup.

Comment: If the 100 threshold has already been reached before the start of the task, it would prevent execution when there is no chance that the output would be used.  You'd have to be sure to use just `get()` not `incrementAndGet()` in that place.

Comment: `executorService.awaitTermination` returns a boolean when it is finished.  Shouldn't this be checked to see if the threads are actually done, and if not, it should wait again?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller. Executor service here is a boiler plate to make sure that your sample runs.  It should be more elaborate in production.  A good start is actually the JavaDoc for `ExecutorService`

Comment: I'm asking because I don't believe the ExecutorService provides any value here.  You still have to poll it using the `awaitTermination` method to know if the Threads have shut down, and that method never returns true unless something actually calls shutdown.   If all the threads get done without calling shutdown, the ExecutorService never gets notified of that termination.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Yes, the `shutdown` call was missing. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could still use an Executor service but use some longer-living Runnables to run the execution and pull the reusable objects from some shared map of objects. Here is a quick example with comments that I think could work for you. **EDIT**: I updated my previous example to meet the requirement of at least 100 pieces of output, but possibly more:

```
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class Example {
    private static AtomicInteger outputCount = new AtomicInteger(0);
    private static SecureRandom rand = new SecureRandom();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        BlockingQueue<Object> expensiveObjects = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
        // Random objects put in
        expensiveObjects.put(new Object());
        expensiveObjects.put(new Object());
        expensiveObjects.put(new Object());
        expensiveObjects.put(new Object());
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
        for (int i = 0 ; i < 4; i++) {
            executorService.execute(new MyRunnable(expensiveObjects));
        }
        // Arbitrary wait in this example.
        executorService.shutdown();
        executorService.awaitTermination(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        System.out.println("Final: " + outputCount.get());
    }

    public static String task() {
        return rand.nextDouble() > 0.5 ? "output" : null;
    }

    /**
     * Runnable that keeps executing while outputCount is less than 100.
     */
    private static class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
        private final BlockingQueue<Object> expensiveObjects;

        public MyRunnable(final BlockingQueue<Object> expensiveObjects) {
            this.expensiveObjects = expensiveObjects;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    Object expensiveObject = expensiveObjects.take();
                    // Use the expensive object that you talked about and put it back for reuse when done. Not needed in this example but leaving it for now
                    String output = task();
                    expensiveObjects.put(expensiveObject);
                    if (output != null) {
                        int counter = outputCount.getAndIncrement();
                        System.out.println(counter);
                        if (counter >= 100) {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    System.out.println("Error!");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In your case it will print 50 lines of output on average.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why it would be 50? Since it is doing outputCount.incrementAndGet() < 100 it will be blocking here and won't execute past 100. It could be changed (as per @StephenOstermiller original request) to just to outputCount.get() < 100 (or just continuously execute) and then increment after work is done if he doesn't care about getting more output than 100.

Comment: OP produces output only in 50% of cases. You `incrementAndGet` in 100% of cases.

Comment: Ah, I understand now. I didn't put the actual `task()` method into my original snippet. Updated my code sample. Thanks for the notice.

Answer (score 1):

- I suggest using a CountDownLatch for limiting the number of output objects to 100
- For delivering the ouput in a thread safe way you could just use a ArrayList which you have decorated with Collections.synchronizedList to make it thread safe
- For accessing the not thread safe operation you could make it thread safe by synchronizing on the expensive object which produces the output object

  ```
  import java.security.SecureRandom;
  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import java.util.Collections;
  import java.util.List;
  import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
  import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
  import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
  import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

  public class CountDownTask implements Runnable{
      private final CountDownLatch latch;
      private final List<String> output;
      private final SecureRandom random;

      public CountDownTask( CountDownLatch latch, List<String> output, SecureRandom random ) {
          super();
          this.latch = latch;
          this.output = output;
          this.random = random;
      }

      public void run() {
          while(latch.getCount() > 0){
              if(getNextValueInAThreadSafeWay() > 0.5){
                  output.add("output");
                  latch.countDown();
              }
          }
      }

      private double getNextValueInAThreadSafeWay(){
          synchronized(random){
              return random.nextDouble();
          }
      }

      public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{
          CountDownLatch theLatch = new CountDownLatch( 100 );
          List<String> output = Collections.synchronizedList( new ArrayList<String>() );
          SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
          ExecutorService service = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
          for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
             service.execute( new CountDownTask( theLatch, output, random ) );
          }
          theLatch.await( 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES );
          service.shutdown();
          System.out.println(output.size());
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: I like the idea of the count down latch.   I don't want to synchronize calls to `SecureRandom.nextDouble` because it is representing the method call that takes 99% of time.  If I did that, I might as well just run the single threaded version.

Comment: Ok I added the synchronized method because you said the expensive object is not thread safe.

Answer (score -1):

Well, here's my shot at it. Worked for me:

```
public class MakeItConcurrent {

    private static final ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
    private static final AtomicInteger outputCount = new AtomicInteger();
    private static final ThreadLocal<SecureRandom> threadToStringBuilder = new ThreadLocal<SecureRandom>();

    public static String task() {
        SecureRandom rand = threadToStringBuilder.get();
        if (rand == null) {
            threadToStringBuilder.set(new SecureRandom());
            rand = threadToStringBuilder.get();
        }
        return rand.nextDouble() > 0.5 ? "output" : null;
    }

    public static void doManyTasks() {
        int currOutputCount;
        while ( ( currOutputCount = outputCount.get() ) < 100) {
            String output = task();
            if (output != null) {
                // outputCount.compareAndSet(currOutputCount, currOutputCount + 1); use this if you want exactly 100 outputs
                outputCount.set(currOutputCount + 1);
                System.out.println(output);
            }
        }
        threadPool.shutdownNow();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {            
            @Override public void run() {
                doManyTasks();
            }
        };
        threadPool.submit(runnable);
        threadPool.submit(runnable);
        threadPool.submit(runnable);
        threadPool.submit(runnable);
        while ( ! threadPool.isShutdown() ) {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }
        System.out.println(outputCount);
    }
}
```

Comment: Broken on many levels by using `outputCount.set(currOutputCount + 1)`

Comment: @AlexanderPogrebnyak care to explain? Bare in mind that OP mentioned the task can give eventually more than 100 outputs. This implementation will **eventually** reach that state.

Comment: @AlexanderPogrebnyak except for that, if the commented part is used `outputCount.compareAndSet(currOutputCount, currOutputCount + 1);` in order to verify the correct next int is set, then it's clear safe on any level.

Comment: The problem here, is that your solution may produce `less` than 100 outputs.

Comment: With `compareAndSet` you have to check the return status, and what do you do if it returns false?